# How do you create complex AngularJS data bindings from Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I working on a basic AngularJS application with a Firebase backend. Part of the database looks like...

```
Student
- FirstName
- LastName
- Schedule
-- Course1
-- Course2...
```

I have a page displaying an html table of students with ng-repeat. Here's the code for my table...

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Youth/Adult</th>
  <th>Courses Selected?</th>
  <th>...</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="(id, student) in students">
    <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.hasSelectedCourses }}</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The controller connecting the data and table together is really straight forward. It's just grabbing the array of students from Firebase and chucking it into $scope.

```
$scope.students = Students;
```

I'm getting students' first and last names, so I know the repeat is working in general. But I'm having difficulty with one particular column I'd like to display - the Courses Selected? column. I'd like to intelligently fill that with a boolean (probably an icon or something) based on the *existance* of the Schedule hanging off the Student in the database. I thought of adding something like this to my controller (don't laugh - still learning JavaScript). This didn't work. The error was that "student" was undefined.

```
$scope.student.hasSelectedCourses = !($scope.student.schedule === null);
```

I think I could do this another way where I actually store hasSelectedCourses as a boolean in the database, but I'm concerned about the integrity of that field and getting into a situation where a student's selected courses and that field are not in sync with each other.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a bit of logic rather than data storage or is storing this in the database the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `student.schedule` is null if no courses selected (which is the normal pattern with firebase):

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="(id, student) in students">
    <td>{{ student.firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.type }}</td>
    <td>
        <span ng-if="student.schedule">Yes<span>
        <span ng-if="!student.schedule">No<span> <!-- these spans could be icons or whatever you want -->
    </td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Alternatively

```
    <td>
        {{student.schedule ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
    </td>
```

A side note: if you aren't already it's well worth it to include AngularFire with your app. The live 3-way binding is a good way to impress.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using AngularFire already. Very handy for learning/practice.